# Grep tools that search multiple strings inside multiple files

Tags: c#, java, sql, string, grep

I realize there seems to be many questions on this forum for searching multiple strings inside files, but I fail to find a solution to search multiple strings inside multiple files.

Using the pipe delimited search result is always an OR statement. What I would like is something that provides an "AND" statement, be it regex or even a tool that allows multiple inputs.

I have tried dnGrep, WinGrep, PowerGrep, and BareGrep, but none of these seem to provide this feature. For those of you that grep stored procedures, I am sure that you understand my pain.

I am trying to search for cases where a couple tables that share the same generic column name exist in stored procedures and with aliasing table names this becomes a huge hassle as I can't just simply search for TableName.ColumnName.

If anyone can help me with this that would be fantastic. If anyone knows of a tool or has written a tool themselves, this would be great. It would also be useful for searching through java and c# code.

Comment: Why can't you do this in SQL?

Comment: `grep somestring thefile | grep otherstring`  ?

Comment: I am uncertain how to do this in SQL as well as searching java and c# files.

And nos, I need to search all code including stored procedures, not a specific file.

Comment: You might take a look at **Gawk**, it sounds like it might fit http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/

Comment: @nos The first grep will give you a list of filenames.  These *filenames* will be searched by the second grep for "otherstring", which isn't what's required.

Comment: @Matt Braunwart If you need to search several files,  just `grep -r somestring . | grep otherstring` , starting from the top folder of all your files.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you want to do. Do you want to find files that contain multiple patterns, NOT on the same line? ie, find all the files of some type that contain 'patternA' AND 'patternB' AND 'patternC', where those 3 patterns can occur on different lines? or do they have to be on the same line?

Comment: @nos Sorry, I was thinking of the case where you are passing multiple files to grep.  However, your solution only succeeds if both of the search terms appear on the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a batch file, search.bat, containing the following:

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq delims=|" %%I in (`findstr /M /C:%2 %1`) do findstr /M /C:%3 "%%I"
```

search.bat takes three parameters.  The first is a wildcarded file name.  The second and third are the search strings.  For example,

```
search *.h deprecated security
```

finds all the header files containing the words "deprecated" and "security".

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want to find all files in a given directory that contain pattern1, pattern2 and pattern3 then:

```
grep -r -l pattern1 . | xargs grep -l pattern2 | xargs grep -l pattern3
```

The -r option recurses to check all files. The -l just lists the files that match. The xargs transforms the list of files from the previous grep into input arguments for the next grep. If you have a lot of patterns, you could put this together in a script or fancy alias.

If you want to restrict the search to certain file types, you can use `find` to first restrict the input files:

```
find . -name "*.h" | xargs grep -l pattern1 | xargs grep -l pattern2 | xargs grep -l pattern3
```